# Why do I get a blank page while loading CGI in tomcat 7?

Tags: perl, tomcat, cgi

I am using tomcat to run CGI. I did all required configuration as per tomcat-CGI docs.

Deleted the comments in web.xml and adding `<Context privileged="true">`. In web.xml, I gave the "cgiPathPrefix" the value "cgi-bin", and I added this cgi-bin folder in the webapps/mycgiproject directory.

When I deploy it tomcat it shows me a blank page. couldn't find a reason since no error or log is generating.

Generally CGI files starts from -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
```

But when i give space it works.

```
 #! /usr/bin/perl -T
```

I am curious though I may find a way for this issue, but want a real solution to this problem ?

Also anyone knows how should be the folder structure inside tomcat.

My configuration is as follows -

```
tomcat/webapps/myperlproject/cgi/"cgi files"
```

in tomcat/conf/web.xml -

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>cgi\</param-value>
</init-param>
```

is it right ?